# Why is deployment taking almost 40mins?

Tags: deployment, migration-tool

I am using the ant migration tool to deploy. The version used in the package.xml is `39`. And i am not triggering any test execution, as i am deploying in a sandbox.

What can be the reason that the deployment time is so high? The number of components as per the deployment screen shows around 500. And this is not a one-off thing, its been taking this many mins for the last 1-months

All the network test like ping, tracert to the instance looks normal.

Below is the console log:
(Request ID's altered)

```
deployCode:
     [echo] Performing the deploy
[sf:deploy] Request for a deploy submitted successfully.
[sf:deploy] Request ID for the current deploy task: 0dfbrekrufhwnvfAR
[sf:deploy] Waiting for server to finish processing the request...
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Pending
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (171/509)  -- Processing Type: Layout
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (224/509)  -- Processing Type: CustomApplication
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (224/509)  -- Processing Type: CustomApplication
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (314/509)  -- Processing Type: Profile
[sf:deploy] Request Status: InProgress (499/509)  -- Processing Type: ForecastingSettings
[sf:deploy] Request Status: Succeeded
[sf:deploy] *********** DEPLOYMENT SUCCEEDED ***********
[sf:deploy] Finished request 0dfbrekrufhwnvfAR successfully.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 41 minutes 53 seconds
```

Comment: This used to happen when I used a custom ant deploy tool (read: a pile of scripts, & later some golang modules) where every now and then it would just stop working for a while. Got so frustrating I stopped using it. I think it has something to do with server limits & request throttling to try to share the instance, and I assume sandbox servers run worse hardware than production, but this is all an educated guess & not a helpful answer.

Comment: i am not counting any other computational time, expect the deployment of the generated 'src' components. And yes, i doubted that multi tenancy might be one of the factors. SF needs to do better with that, cant have an agile environment with 40mins to kill while deploying

Comment: This is what i hear back from sf support. My Analysis :- As per server logs, it's quit possible to take 35 to 40 minutes during deployment process, because it's asynchronous process and totally depends on Server resource availability. However, in the above deployment where total time spent processing on entities is 2141637 milliseconds. For more information

Comment: please go through below useful link :-

https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__developer.salesforce.com_docs_atlas.en-2Dus.dev-5Flifecycle.meta_dev-5Flifecycle_migrate-5Ftime-5Ffactors.htm&d=DwIFAw&c=jozbAXBGpZCeJmn-Q9SThA&r=qwBXQA5-efe36INti6zWBRM3WOl69KltKADjmJiGAPw&m=lFNF7_pjEOw8Cx1-_ZsGxj8f1nmZjNqb5sg44srWd9w&s=hXvPWvwG-f1wheexu6tt2NQDXv0HwzlstgxnG_3WeTY&e=